# Is it possible to have a vertical recycler view with different widths for each row?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, width, staggeredgridlayout, vertical-scroll

I am creating a recycler view and I have 2 types of itemviews in it. Each item view would have different widths(55dp for one and MatchParent for the another). If I create a recycler view with first 4 rows having width 55dp and the next 2 rows with width MatchParent, do you think my entire recycler view would have same width throughout? Or will it be 55 width for first 4 rows and MatchParent for the last 2 rows?
Please note I have set the width and height as wrapContent for the recycler view and using staggeredGridLayoutManager with single column and vertical scroll.
I only want a single column vertical scrolling recycler view with different widths at each row.

If you can imagine, it should look like an L - shaped recycler view.

Comment: In have upvoted cause it is a good question (need editing though).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have items in RecyclerView to have **different height and width.**

You should give **wrap content** for both list item and RecyclerView

Comment: I have actually made wrapContent for recycler view but for the itemviews, I strictly want them to be occupying 55dp for first 4 rows and need the last 2 rows to occupy the entire screen width.

Comment: List items are same right for both the items? Only the text content is less in second one?

Comment: Not really. The list items are totally different and also the content in them is.

Comment: RecyclerView can bind ONLY one type of item. If you need different item with different contents within in then you should create two different RecyclerView and list items.